# how to rename a VM using libvirt+KVM

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

How can I rename a VM on KVM+libvirt?

I would like it to change the name in the 'inventory' as well as change the name of the storage etc.

Comment: after I asked this question the fine folks on the libvirt project have added the 'virsh edit my-vm-name' command.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

run

```
virsh dumpxml name_of_vm > name_of_vm.xml
```

Undefine the old vm to prevent an error because of an duplicate UUID.

```
virsh undefine name-of-vm
```

Edit the xml file then import it.

```
virsh define name_of_vm.xml
```

Of course you will have to stop and start the vm for the changes to take effect

```
virsh destroy name_of_vm
virsh start name_of_vm
```

Comment: need to add one step: (before defining the vm with the new name)  "virsh undefine  name-of-vm" otherwise it complains about duplicate UUID.

Comment: i also had to rename the hd.img file and edit the line in the xml file

Comment: Correct order is in the other answer. You don't have to rename img if you don't use the old machine.

Comment: This answer is now out of date. See my answer below. tldr; virsh now has domrename.

Answer (score 16):

```
virsh dumpxml myvm > foo.xml
<edit foo.xml, change the name, move storage>
virsh undefine myvm
virsh define foo.xml
```

Source: https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvirt-users/2010-October/msg00072.html

Answer (score 16):

`virsh` implemented `domrename` in release 1.2.19: Sep 02 2015. So the current best practice is just:

```
 virsh domrename oldname newname
```

As you might expect, thedomain must be stopped, but also it cannot have any snapshots.

Comment: +1 - you can `virsh edit newname` and change the file path and `mv oldname newname` to rename the directory if you want everything to match.

Comment: in other words, you also have to 1)  rename /var/lib/libvirt/images/oldname.qcow2 in /var/lib/libvirt/images/newname.qcow2 ; and 2) edit /etc/libvirt/qemu/newname.xml to set the correct source file balise <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/newname.qcow2'

Comment: but only if you need the filenames to match the domainnames (which I admit, is convenient) - this avoids a destroy/create cycle, though still requires a stop (and no snapshots)

Answer (score 5):

To change many machines you can use this:

```
virsh shutdown old-name
```

Wait for above to finish and run:

```
virsh dumpxml old-name > old-name.xml
virsh undefine old-name
```

Wait for above to finish and run:

```
sed -i 's/<name>old-name<\/name>/<name>new-name<\/name>/g' old-name.xml
virsh define old-name.xml
```

Run this one-by-one for each machine. You can use this RegExp if you have a list containing `old-name  new-name`:

```
([^\r\n]+?)[ \t]+([^\r\n]+)
virsh shutdown $1\n#WAIT!\nvirsh dumpxml $1 > $1.xml\nvirsh undefine $1\n\#WAIT!\nsed -i 's/<name>$1<\\/name>/<name>$2<\\/name>/g' $1.xml\nvirsh define $1.xml\n
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it little differently and may be un-recommended method (not sure).

`virsh destroy old-vm
virsh edit old-vm`

In the XML change

1. domain name old-vm to new-vm
2. change a char/digit in UUID 
   save and exit.

`virsh list --all`

1 old-vm  shut-off

2 new-vm  shut-off

Now undefine the old-vm

`virsh undefine old-vm`